# How to expand the text field in data viewer in R using View

Tags: r

I have a single-column data frame with each row containing a tweet. I am learning how to clean the tweets and would like to be able to see the results of my efforts. However, if I use the function `View()`, while I get a spreadsheet-like data viewer, I am unable to expand the text field by pulling to the right using the mouse to see the entire tweet.

What should I do so that I can see the complete tweet in every row and hence observe the changes being made to the tweets, as I go about cleaning them. Is there a better way of doing this other than using `View()`?

[image]

Comment: Are things like `df$V3`, `head(df$V3, 3)`, `df$V3[5:10]` unacceptable? Why?

Comment: I can do that. However, I am curious to know why I cannot expand the text cells in the data viewer using the mouse. The option appears when I hover the mouse near the right edge, but I cannot expand the cells.

Comment: If the content of a cell with textual data is not shown entirely in `View()`, this clipped view is indicated by three little dots. If you move the cursor over them, the full text should emerge.

Comment: Thanks...I was able to see that. However, is there no way to see the full text in all the rows simultaneously?